# Error creating database

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I am creating a database by using following schema ...... using microsoft sql server....

```
 CREATE DATABASE /*!32312 IF NOT EXISTS*/`stacks`/*!40100 
 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 */;(Line 15)

 USE `stacks`;

/*Table structure for table `answers` */
```

Got An error like this ...while executing , i dont know....

```
 Error :  Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 15
      Incorrect syntax near '`'.
```

would any one pls help on this.....

Many Thanks in advance ....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like your syntax is from MySQL. Why do you have back-ticks and "default character set"? This is not SQL Server syntax. Please see the *SQL Server* docs for CREATE DATABASE: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176061.aspx

Answer (score 5):

Did you look up SQL Server [CREATE DATABASE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176061.aspx) and [identifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175874.aspx) syntax?

All you need is `CREATE DATABASE stacks;`

Your code is for MySQL